# can't access function in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to print a linked list, when I write the hole program in tha main function it works fine, but when I tried to separate it to different functions and call the "print list" from main it doesn't work

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
next EQU 4
.data

sundaystr byte 'today sunday  ', 0
mondaystr byte 'monday   ',0
tuesdaystr byte "tuesday  ",0

sunday dword sundaystr
dword monday
dword 0

monday dword mondaystr
dword tuesday
dword sunday

tuesday dword tuesdaystr
dword 0
dword monday

.code

main PROC
push offset sunday
call printList
Exit
main ENDP

printlist PROC

push edx
push esi
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov esi, [ebp+12]

print:
   mov edx,[esi]
   call writestring
   add esi, next
   cmp [esi],  dword ptr 0
   je done
   mov esi,[esi]
loop print
done:
pop ebp
pop esi
pop edx
ret 
printlist endp

END main
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* doesn't tell me any information. Can you detail what you mean by this?

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is rarely a good problem description. Please provide more details, such as what error are you getting if any, and when you are getting it (compile or run time).

Comment: Here is the exaption : Unhandled exception at 0x00401B3C in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0DE800CC. I'm sure that I'm not using the stack like i should

Comment: `call` pushes the address of the instruction following itself onto the stack. That's the address you're getting when you read from `[ebp+12]`. Try `[ebp+16]` if you want the stacked `offset sunday` value.

Answer (score 0):

`CALL` pushes `EIP` on the stack, since `RET` needs that information to be able to return. You have to take that into account when you offset the stack pointer to access function arguments.

```
push edx
push esi
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov esi, [ebp+12]
```

At the point where you do `mov esi, [ebp+12]` you'll have the old value of `ebp` at `[ebp+0]`, `esi` at `[ebp+4]`, `edx` at `[ebp+8]`, *and the old value of `EIP` at `[ebp+12]`*.

I'm guessing that you really wanted the address you pushed at `push offset sunday`, which you'll find at `[ebp+16]`.